# OpenModelica: Translation Warning In component in relation on Real numbers is only allowed inside functions

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I'm trying to model Coulomb static friction in a multi-body system based on the equations from this [physics.stackexchange.com](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/348240/modeling-static-coulomb-friction-in-a-multibody-system/348254#348254) post. I have written a very primitive Modelica code to test the equations you may see in this [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/Foadsf/a106ec3658df3c1537ff3c2858d50ba6). I have two main issues:

1. First of all I get this warning:

> Translation Warning
>        [multibody_Coulomb_static_friction: 43:3-47:9]: In component , in relation V1 == V2,  ==  on Real numbers is only allowed inside functions.

what does it mean and how I can fix this?

2. The simulation takes like ages to finish. why is it? does it have anything to do with this warning? is there anyway I can do the simulation faster?

**P.S.1.** I tried running the code in Wolfram SystemModeler, but there it doesn't even succeed to run and I got a error which I have reported [here in wolfram forum](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1152013?p_p_auth=iPyv88BL)!

**P.S.2** I have posted similar questions [here](https://openmodelica.org/forum/default-topic/2263-openmodelica-translation-warning) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54782904/4999991).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're trying to re-invent the wheel. You say that you want to create a multibody model, but you are not using the Multibody library. Use that. And couple that with rotational or translational components that use friction. An example with such components:
 [Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Examples.Friction](http://reference.wolfram.com/system-modeler/libraries/Modelica/Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Examples.Friction.html)