# OpenModelica complains about a negative value which can't be negative

Tags: modelica, openmodelica, jmodelica, systemmodeler

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54782904/including-a-causal-relation-in-a-modelica-simulation-leads-to-translation-error) I have modified the energy based controller which I have described [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ControlTheory/comments/asvr4e/an_energy_based_controller_with_minimum_overshoot/) to avoid negative values inside the `sqrt`:

```
model Model
  //constants
  parameter Real m = 1;
  parameter Real k = 2;
  parameter Real Fmax = 3;
  parameter Real x0 = 1;
  parameter Real x1 = 2;
  parameter Real t1 = 5;
  parameter Real v0 = -2;

  //variables
  Real x, v, a, xy, F, vm, K;

initial equation
  x = x0;
  v = v0;

equation
  v = der(x);
  a = der(v);
  m * a + k * x = F;

algorithm
  if time < t1 then
    xy := x0;
  else
    xy := x1;
  end if;
  
  K := Fmax * abs(xy - x) + k * (xy^2 - x^2) / 2;
  
  if abs(xy - x) < 1e-6 then
    F := k * x;
  else
    if K > 0 then
      vm := sign(xy - x) * sqrt(2 * K / m);
      F := Fmax * sign(vm - v);
    else
      F := Fmax * sign(x - xy);
    end if;
  end if;
  
  annotation(
    experiment(StartTime = 0, StopTime = 20, Tolerance = 1e-06, Interval = 0.001),
    __OpenModelica_simulationFlags(lv = "LOG_STATS", outputFormat = "mat", s = "euler"));
end Model;
```

However, it keeps giving me the error:

> The following assertion has been violated at time 7.170000
>
> Model error: Argument of sqrt(K / m) was -1.77973e-005 should be >= 0
>
> Integrator attempt to handle a problem with a called assert.
>
> The following assertion has been violated at time 7.169500
>
> Model error: Argument of sqrt(K / m) was -6.5459e-006 should be >= 0
>
> model terminate | Simulation terminated by an assert at the time: 7.1695
>
> STATISTICS
>
> Simulation process failed. Exited with code -1.

I would appreciate if you could help me know what is the problem and how I can solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you created does event localization to find out when the condition in the if-statements becomes true and/or false.  During this search it is possible that the expression in the square-root becomes negative although you 'avoided' it with the if-statement.

Try reading [this](http://book.xogeny.com/behavior/discrete/decay/) and to apply the solution presented there. Spoiler: It basically comes down to adding a `noEvent()` statement for you Boolean condition...

Comment: thanks a lo. changing the `K > 0` to `noEvent(K > 0)` solved the problem. Also proving there is something fundamentally wrong with my controller. :)